# How to create RESTful service with main method associated with it

Tags: java, rest

I am newbie to java and RESTful services.
I have an java application (consisting of threads) which has read(), insert(), update() and delete() functions in it.

Now I want to transform this application into RESTful services as GET, POST, PUT and DELETE calls. my problem is I have few statements which does some thread initialisation in 'main' method and also does some configuration.

I can design REST controller for this application, but it will only serve when some requests are coming for it. I want to execute those statements in main method also, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you use any library or framework like JAX-RS?

Comment: i am using JAX-RS.

Comment: OK, what else? Do you build a war for Tomcat, do you use Spring Boot or Dropwizard? There are many options to build and a RESTful application in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. I will take one class which implement `ServletContextListener` interface that I will include in web.xml and that class will initialise all things which i want.